# How do I extract stress/strain at sectionpoints using abaqus python script?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def get_field(odb, step, frame, field, element):
    if field == 'E':
        function = get_strain
        for f in odb.steps[step].frames[frame].fieldOutputs[field].getSubset(region=element_set).values:
            data = function(f.data)
            dict_data[index] = data
            index += 1
        return dict_data
```

I want to include section points and section category. What should I change in this code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another getSubset:

```
   fo = ..... fieldOutput object
   f = fo.getSubset(sectionPoint=sp)
```

Section point objects can be found in the odb:

```
   odbname = 'mine.odb'
   odb = session.odbs[odbname]
   sp = odb.sectionCategories.values()[0]
```

If you want a particular section point number, each section Point object has the property

```
   sp.number
```